What does the word exception mean in this phrase?
I was reading an article on Burmese pythons in Florida and came across this sentence:

“Because of their large size, adult Burmese pythons have few predators, with humans being the exception”

What does “with humans being the exception mean”? Does it mean humans are an obvious predator but they aren’t including them in the list of what the few predators of the Burmese python are?
Link to the article: https://myfwc.com/wildlifehabitats/profiles/reptiles/snakes/burmese-python/

There's no justification for including the word obvious. Humans are the exception to the statement Adult Burmese pythons have few predators. The fact that it says the exception rather than an exception means (in the writer's opinion) there are no other animals that prey on adult Burmese pythons. What is obvious is that if you make  a list of "predators of adult Burmese pythons", humans will be in that list for sure. But whereas the word few [predators] implies there should be other animals in that list, the word the [exception] implies there aren't.

...of course, it may be that few simply means hardly any humans would prey on adult Burmese pythons, rather than hardly any other predators. I could certainly go with that (I personally have no intention of hunting adult Burmese pythons myself, so certainly not all humans predate on ABP's! :)

“ whereas the word few [predators] implies there should be other animals in that list, the word the [exception] implies there aren't.”
So the sentence in the article is wrong right? “Few” and “exception” contradict each other based on your last sentence

It's a very fine point, that I wouldn't have even noticed if you hadn't put the sentence under the microscope. And as @fred2 says, humans don't really "predate" ABPs anyway. To a first approximation, I don't see any problem with either the "few predators / the exception" conflict, OR the labeling of humans as "predators" of ABP. But you asked What does “with humans being the exception" mean? And like I said, it means Humans are the exception. They're not only "included in the list" - they are the [complete] list of what the few predators of the Burmese python are.

My question lies with the contradiction between "few" and "exception". When you say humans are the exception, it would mean that humans are the only predators of the Burmese python. You said "they are the complete list", if they are the complete list, how can you say the Burmese python has a "few" predators? Doesn't "few" mean you have at least more than 1 type of predator?

It's not a contradiction. The exception means that humans are the one species which is definitely on the list. Few is a qualifier saying it's unlikely there are other predators, but I can't guarantee it. (I can't definitively rule out any alligator attacks on pythons over the last 200 years.)

predator meaning
noun
an animal that kills and eats other animals.. To use this term for human beings is incorrect.

For all I know, there are "other predators" of Burmese pythons in Burma (or other places where they've always lived). But they're an invasive species in Florida, and it's often the case that invasive species overrun their new habitat precisely because none of the (few) predators they normally have to face actually live in the new habitat. Obviously there has to be some leeway, since an "adult" might be anywhere from 2m long (alligator lunch) to 5m long (only likely to be killed by humans).

@JamesMathai: Though it is not illegal to eat python meat, the Florida Department of Health recently finalized a consumption advisory for Burmese pythons found in Florida, advising “Do Not Consume Python” due to the high levels of mercury found in python meat. The fact that it's called "python meat", and that officials have "advised against" eating it, suggests that at least some people are truly predating them. The text says there are only a few (but not zero) predators / people eating them..

@FumbleFingers I thought the word 'predator' was only used for animals.

That's really pointless nitpicking. Obviously the initial reference is to few wild predators, and only a seriously anal writer would avoid saying humans are the exception purely because we wouldn't normally say Humans are predators of pythons. Also note that the OP isn't even questioning that aspect of the text, just the exact scope of the word "few". The text as cited is perfectly good English, and it doesn't reflect well on this site that so many people want to find fault with just about any text presented for clarification.

I think the author has expressed themselves poorly. What they mean is

Burmese pythons have few predators, with humans being by far their greatest threat.

If something has "few" predators, a predator that dominates the statistics cannot logically be an "exception". There is also some ambiguity about whether control by humans is conventionally considered "predation", so the author is somewhat playing fast and loose with terminology.
All in all, it could have been expressed better.

Thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, when you said “If something has "few" predators, a predator that dominates the statistics cannot logically be an "exception”.” — what you mean here is that exception means there should be only 1 predator, but the word few indicates there isn’t just 1 predator, right?

I don't think it's reasonable to say "the author has expressed themselves poorly". I've only glanced at the full context, but all I can say is anyone who could write English at that level should never have any reason to ask questions on a site aimed at non-Anglophone learners. In context, it's pedantic quibbling to suggest that "predation" isn't the right word for what humans in Florida do to Burmese pythons. Obviously those humans are a "threat" to the pythons, which are a seriously unwanted invasive species!

@penguin99 Yes, that's right. Humans are not an 'exception' to  the few predators, they are the dominant predator of the few that exist.

@FumbleFingers ... I'm not sure I completely follow. The author can clearly write well, but even the best writers sometimes express themselves imperfectly. It would be entirely clear to most 'native' readers what the author meant, hence it got past the sub-editors, but, as the OP illustrates, there is a fault in the logic of the sentence which can trip up somebody reading the sentence literally.

@FumbleFingers  Yes it is a little pedantic to quibble about the use of 'predation', but predation is defined as "the fact that an animal hunts, kills, and eats other animals" (Cambridge). The author is mixing the scientific definition of predation in that sense with a more metaphorical use of the word to describe human biological control of animals considered to be pests. (Admittedly, the distinction is unlikely to make much difference to the snakes ;-) .) In a context where clarity is paramount, such as a government agency website, it could be written a little better.

Well, it's not unreasonable to assume an implicit context of within Florida for either or both statements (that ABP have few predators and that humans predate on ABP). I don't know how many Burmese pythons are killed in Florida, or what proportion of the killings are people seeking free / exotic "swamp meat" (cf "bush meat" in Africa), but it seems pretty certain that at least some are indeed eaten. We are talking about a country where presidential candidate Robert F Kennedy Jr stuck a dead roadkill bear in the boot of his car, intending to butcher and eat it later!

If it's clear to all readers what was meant, who cares about "incorrect" use of the word "predators", given that word was already present and available to be reused? I still don;t see any reason to find fault.

We'll have to agree to disagree. It's hardly a crime against English comprehension, but on a first reading I did feel it could be put better, to avoid the kind of logical inconsistency that the OP and I both discerned.
